# Use x-editable for multiple buttons in Meteor

Tags: javascript, jquery, meteor, x-editable

I want to use x-editable inputs for multiple buttons in Meteor.

My code looks like this:

```
{{#each player}}
    <button name="new-game" class="btn btn-primary btn-block glyphicon glyphicon-plus new-game" type="button"></button>
{{/each}}
```

[image]

How can I add input fields for different buttons?

Comment: How is that supposed to look like? Under every button editable input?

Comment: After clicking on one button there should be a popup on the right side with a simple input field. The problem is, that I can't address one button specifically. Furthermore, I don't know how to display x-editable popups for buttons. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You should create another pool with input like this:

```
{{#each player}}
    <button name="new-game" class="btn btn-primary btn-block glyphicon glyphicon-plus new-game" type="button"></button>
    <input type="text" style="display:none"></input>
{{/each}}
```

Helper

```
'click button': function(event){
    $(event.currentTarget).next().css("display","block");
}
```

Comment: Could you please post a full example? You are suggesting that I should include an input field and make it visible/invisible?

Comment: This is full example, just paste it in correct places

Comment: Thanks for your help, but this will only make a simple input field not a x-editable popup.

Comment: I just looked up documentation, how about $(event.currentTarget).editable()?

Comment: Thanks for that! When I click on the button, "Empty" will be added within it. Then I have to click again and the editable popup will appear. So one step closer, but how can I remove the "Empty" text and immediately show the popup after clicking the button? In addition, when I click "save" the input text will be added within the button. How can I stop the automatic element update with the new value?

Comment: Hmm it looks like it has to be applied at startup, so try using Meteor.startup event, and in it something like $('button').each(function(){ $(this).editable()}); - I'm not sure if I made each loop correctly

Comment: Thank you, I did it with the `rendered` function. However, the buttons have text elements ("Empty") and if I click on save, the elements will be updated. Do you know how I can solve this, because for my purpose, I don't need the text elements to be updated.

Comment: display: null or display: ""

Comment: No, sorry for the wrong information. `display: false` just works fine. Thank you so much for your help. Have a nice day! You made my day.